# electron fail when run build version

Tags: electron, atom-editor

I am having a problem with electron to run the version build on Windows, Mac

A Javascript error ocurred in the main process

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'electron'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fabuy/lab/tilo-desktop/releases/tilo-desktop-darwin-x64/tilo-desktop.app/Contents/Resources/app/main.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fabuy/lab/tilo-desktop/releases/tilo-desktop-darwin-x64/tilo-desktop.app/Contents/Resources/atom.asar/browser/lib/init.js:123:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue should be with the electron version with which the deploy-able packages were built. For more details refer this [link](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/issues/205).

I had similar sought of errors with the packages that were built with 'electron-packager-interactive'(epi) npm package. As i debug more, I have found that my epi package by default has used '0.34.1' version. So, upgrading to later version of '0.35.0' had resolved the error.